# How to reference a column in relation to another column for a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,"cat","mouse", 'tiger'],
    ["tiger","dog","elephant", "mouse"],
    ["cat",np.nan,"giraffe", "cat"],
    [np.nan,np.nan,"ant", "ant"]],  columns=["animal1","animal2","animal3", "animal4"])

print(df)



  animal1 animal2   animal3 animal4
0     NaN     cat     mouse   tiger
1   tiger     dog  elephant   mouse
2     cat     NaN   giraffe     cat
3     NaN     NaN       ant     ant
```

So in my real data there are more columns....

but I'm trying to loop through column 1 and 2, and use fillna to fill in the NaNs using data from column 3 and 4 respectively.

So animal1's NaNs are filled using animal3's data, and animal2's Nans are filled using animal4.

I tried something like below fully knowing it won't work, but might demonstrate what I would like:

```
for column in df.iloc[:,0:1]:
    column.fillna(df.iloc[:, +2])
```

So there are two problems:

1. How do I integrate 'fillna' into a for loop?
2. How do I target a column in reference to the column of interest?

Comment: Is using a for loop needed?

Comment: No it isn't! Any solutions welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution, let's use `combine_first` with some index renaming to take advantage of pandas instrinsic data alignment:

```
df.combine_first(df[['animal3', 'animal4']].set_axis(['animal1', 'animal2'], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  animal1 animal2   animal3 animal4
0   mouse     cat     mouse   tiger
1   tiger     dog  elephant   mouse
2     cat     cat   giraffe     cat
3     ant     ant       ant     ant
```

### Details

`combine_first` fills NaN in df.  Using `set_axis` we rename 'animal3' and `animal4' to 'animal1' and 'animal2' matching those NaN we want to replace.  Now, pandas will align the operation to happen on like dataframe indexes and column headers.

---

##### Update using column positions:

```
df.combine_first(df[df.columns[2:4]].set_axis(df.columns[0:2], axis=1))
```

Comment: Is there a way of replacing the explicit naming of columns with .iloc instead? I have many more columns than this, so it would be good if I could use this on a large set of columns.

Comment: Yes. you can use the df.columns with index slicing.  Something like this:   `df[df.columns[2:4]].set_axis(df.columns[0:2], axis=1)`

Comment: @Jameson See update. Now if you need some complex slicing look at `np.r_`.

Comment: This worked and is very clean and simply, but the output rearranges the columns from its original order. e.g. animal3 column is now to the right of animal1 (or column 2 is now next to column 0)

Comment: You could add `.reindex(df.columns, axis=1)` at the end to get the original column order back.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to iterate them manually in a for loop, just assign the columns using `bfill` on `axis=1`

```py
df[['animal1',  'animal3']] = df[['animal1',  'animal3']].bfill(axis=1)
df[['animal2',  'animal4']] = df[['animal2',  'animal4']].bfill(axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  animal1 animal2   animal3 animal4
0   mouse     cat     mouse   tiger
1   tiger     dog  elephant   mouse
2     cat     cat   giraffe     cat
3     ant     ant       ant     ant
```

For doing it for such multiple pairs:

```py
for c1,c2 in zip(df.columns[:df.shape[1]//2], df.columns[df.shape[1]//2:])::
    df[[c1,c2]] = df[[c1,c2]].bfill(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! In my actual use case, there are way more columns that doing this would be laborious.

Comment: @Jameson, It can be easily modified to support for multiple columns, if the pattern is the same. i.e. filling first half using last half along the columns.

Answer (score 2):

We can create column groups based on a modulus (2) of a RangeIndex over columns created by [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), to group even and odd columns, then [`groupby bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) to populate values across groups:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) % 2, axis=1).bfill()
```

Or with [`Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) instead of `np.arange`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.get_indexer(df.columns) % 2, axis=1).bfill()
```

`df`:

```
  animal1 animal2   animal3 animal4
0   mouse     cat     mouse   tiger
1   tiger     dog  elephant   mouse
2     cat     cat   giraffe     cat
3     ant     ant       ant     ant
```

---

If needing explicit mapping [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) can be used to assign groups (Note grouping is slightly modified in example below).

Hard coded mapping:

```
group_map = {'animal1': 0, 'animal2': 1, 'animal3': 1, 'animal4': 0}
df = df.groupby(df.columns.map(group_map), axis=1).bfill()
```

Programmatic mapping:

```
group_map = {
    k: v for v, lst in enumerate([
        ['animal1', 'animal4'],  # Group 0
        ['animal2', 'animal3']   # Group 1
    ]) for k in lst
}
df = df.groupby(df.columns.map(group_map), axis=1).bfill()
```

Both produce:

```
  animal1  animal2   animal3 animal4
0   tiger      cat     mouse   tiger  # Col 1 filled from Col 4
1   tiger      dog  elephant   mouse
2     cat  giraffe   giraffe     cat  # Col 2 filled from Col 3
3     ant      ant       ant     ant
```

Comment: This is a great and comprehensive answer, but seems quite complicated (for me!). I need to go away and breakdown what is happening to be able to utilise it. Thanks so much though

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate over certain columns you can just add the for loop as shown. Especially when the diff is always 2 columns.
Otherwise the 3 row does the trick.

```
list_of_columns = [0,1]
for col_index in list_of_columns:
    df.iloc[:,col_index] = df.iloc[:,col_index].fillna(df.iloc[:,col_index +2])
```

**Output:**

```
0   mouse     cat     mouse   tiger
1   tiger     dog  elephant   mouse
2     cat     cat   giraffe     cat
3     ant     ant       ant     ant
```

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not the most efficient but still general working use:

**YOUR DF**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,"cat","mouse", 'tiger'],
    ["tiger","dog","elephant", "mouse"],
    ["cat",np.nan,"giraffe", "cat"],
    [np.nan,np.nan,"ant", "ant"]],  columns=["animal1","animal2","animal3", "animal4"])
```

**SIMPLE FOR LOOP**

```
for i in range(df['animal1'].shape[0]):
    if df['animal1'][i] is np.nan:
        df['animal1'][i] = df['animal3'][i]
    if df['animal2'][i] is np.nan:
        df['animal2'][i] = df['animal4'][i]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    animal1 animal2 animal3  animal4
0   mouse   cat     mouse    tiger
1   tiger   dog     elephant mouse
2   cat     cat     giraffe  cat
3   ant     ant     ant      ant
```

Comment: Thanks but this wouldn't be efficient for large numbers of columns.